# Select Top N files based on modification date and rsync them

Tags: command-line, server, bash, rsync, transfer

I'm fairly new to linux and I'm trying to transfer some *N* files based on **Modification Date**.

I've found this command`ls -tr | head -100`, which to my understanding, will list the Top 100 Files (*head -100)* Based on **modification date** (*-t, newest first)* **but reversed** (*-r reverses the list, so it's oldest first now?)*.

But then in my next step, which is to *rsync* them, I still can't figure out if I can use **|** (*pipe character)*  or **&&** *(ampersand)*

so for now i have this:
`ls -tr | head -350 | rsync * <remote-host>`,but apparently `rsync *` will transfer everything. So I'm stuck with this for now. should I put the first 2 commands in the rsync? or could I use `awk` command?

any help/head-up is gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use find.

```
find DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt DATE -exec rsync {} destination \;
```

So, lets say, you want to rsync files in a specific directory, with no folder or files in folders in the specific directory from 21 September 2014 until now. The command you will need to run is

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt 20140921 -exec rsync {} destination \;
```

Comment: It might better to use `+` instead of `\;` to start fewer rsync programs.

Comment: @nathan-adams Can i also use the _-name_ option in find for specifying the files to transfer? 


@muru does it make a big difference between `+` and `\;`? I was planning to put this in a script/crontab entry

Comment: Certainly,  so  ` find /path/to/dir -name "name" -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt 20140921 -exec rsync {} destination \;`

Comment: @paacharon3 that depends on how many files you have. For a few dozen, not much. For a few hundred or more, it might make a lot of difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Using this command worked great for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the filenames don't contain whitespace or non-ASCII characters, you can use

```
rsync `ls -tp | grep -v / | head -n <n>` <destination> <options>
```

Comment: I was actually thinking something similar to this but i just cant' get it to work last time. Can you explain further what `grep -v /` means?

Comment: It removes all directories from the output of `ls` using the slash that was added with the -p switch.